# How to fix bad moving parts?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have bad moving parts in posemode.Take a look at the picture,when in pose mode the panty is not moving with body.all the meshes are perfect but both thighs bones are not working good
here is a link http://sta.sh/01frq6ke1cns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the bone you want the panties to be parented to then go to Weight paint mode ((shortcut) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in object mode) and weight paint them.

See if it works now: http://www.filedropper.com/kok2

Comment: I try it but its not working i will upload file.

Comment: I adjusted some stuff in your blend file, see if it does what you want

Comment: Sorry for the late but you fixed my model or chang my blend file setting?because its empty